# Spring-MVC: find mapping details by its name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, request-mapping

Spring-MVC's `@RequestMapping` annotation has parameter "name" which can be used for identifying each resource.

For some circumstances I need access this information on fly: retrieve mapping details (e.g. `path`) by given name.

Sure I can scan for classes for this annotation and retrieve needed instances via:

```
 ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
 scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(RequestMapping.class));
 // ... find classes ... go through its methods ...
```

But it is quite ugly. Is any more simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to get all your mappings and filter them based on name. Following is a code snippet which creates a rest api and returns the path details of a api/mapping.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

@RestController
public class EndpointController {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

    @GetMapping("endpoints/{name}")
    public String show(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        String output = name + "Not Found";
        Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> methods = this.handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();

        for (Map.Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> entry : methods.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getName() != null && entry.getKey().getName().equals(name)) {
                output = entry.getKey().getName() + " : " + entry.getKey();
                break;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

The above is just an example, You can use the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` anyway you want until you can autowire it.